# How can I change the keyboard shortcut priority in Windows Remote Desktop Connection?

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop

I have a Windows Remote Desktop Connection client open. When I enter a 
 keyboard shortcut it gets sent to the remote desktop. Is it possible to configure Windows Remote Desktop Connection so that the keyboard shortcut first get sent to the host Windows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the built-in option.

1. Disconnect from the host.
2. Reopen Remote Desktop Connection
3. Click "Show Options"
4. Select the "Local Resources" tab
5. Set "Apply Windows key combinations" to "On this computer" (or "Only when using the full screen" if you prefer)

[image]